# Аудио не воспроизводится

Tags: ios, swift

Я использую этот код для воспроизведения аудио. Мой код отлично работает на iOS 14 со всеми моделями наушников, но когда пользователи обновили свои устройства до iOS 15 и используют AirPods Pro, аудиофайлы не воспроизводятся. На других моделях AirPods и при воспроизведении аудиофайлов через динамик iPhone все работает. Что произошло. Как это исправить?

**После долгого ожидания я получил AirPods Pro. И сначала я удалил эту строку `setupMediaPlayerNotificationView (true)`, и приложение воспроизводило звук нормально. Но некоторые функции на экране блокировки были не работали. А с этой строчкой в ​​приложении звука не было. В App Store у меня было 3 приложения с одинаковым кодом. А после ios 15 работало только одно. И я никак не понимал в чем причина, если код такой же. Почему другие не работают? Но оказалось, что в названии работающего приложения было 1 слово - `Build Settings -> Product Name -> «myAppName»`. А у остальных было несколько слов. И когда я переименовал их в 1 слово, все работало нормально. Звук воспроизводится нормально. Что это было? Я все еще не понимаю? Если у кого-то есть версия, поделитесь.**

код:

```
 let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(masterIndex)0", withExtension: "m4a")!
            
     do {
                
     audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
     audioPlayer.delegate = self
     audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
     play(sender:AnyObject.self as AnyObject)
                
     setupMediaPlayerNotificationView(true)
     lockScreen()
                
     } catch {
                
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить withExtension: "m4a" на withExtension: "m4r" второй вариант переконвертировать файлы m4a в m4r

Comment: А Вы уверены в этом? Просто чтобы мне попробовать нужно обновить приложение т.к. у меня нет AirPods Pro). Не могу протестировать сам. Я не совсем пойму почему тогда файл m4a работал нормально на iOS 14 с AirPods Pro?

Comment: @User Я не уверен, а предложил как вариант, не обновляйте, а попросите кого-то у кого есть эти наушники

Comment: А если я этот файл прослушаю по ссылке в Safari через AirPods Pro, то там он тоже не будет работать?

Comment: @User Должен. Почитал на иностранных форумах пишут что после обновления до IOS15 нужно и обновить что-то у  Airpods Pro. Толи прошивку то ли приложение, не помню, попробуйте сами поискать

Comment: Проблема остается даже с mp3